# В каких случаях в веб-программировании используются данные единицы измерения - hardware pixels, CSS px, dip?

Tags: android, css, responsive

Привет.

Вопрос по пикселям. Запутался в них. Вот ссылка на видео на Youtube: «[A Pixel is Not a Pixel: Learn about Viewports with PPK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wscVOXjIzQ)».

Есть пиксели железа, есть *CSS*-пиксели (они указываются в CSS-селекторах) и есть *density independent pixels*. Свойство `window.aspectPixelRatio` рассчитывается как раз по DIP-пикселям. Кучу всего перечитал и по русски, и по-английски. Ничего не понял. Везде одно и тоже (скопипастили из стандарта).

**Хочу чтобы человек четко объяснил, зачем нужны три вида пикселей, когда какой вид пикселей используется и как переводить один вид пикселя в другой вид.**

Объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах:

1. Как переводить эти три вида пикселей друг в друга.
2. Когда какой вид пикселей используется?
3. Что такое зум на обычном мониторе и на телефоне?
4. Во *viewport* (*layout viewport* и *visual viewport*) тоже хочу разобраться.

Comment: Поводу viewpoint. То в css есть два типа размера viewpoint - view height и view width. Т.е. тут размер уже зависит только от размера рабочей области. Допустим если ширина области 500 пикселей, то 1vw будет равен сразу 5 пикселям. Если высота области 300 пикселей, то 1vh будет равен 3. Однако это не запрещает использовать дробные значения vp, например .5vw или .vh. Zoom фактор при этом не влияет на размер. Размер зависит только от рабочей области. Допустим растягивая/сужая ширину области, размер единицы viewpoint тоже изменится на соответствующую величину.

Answer (score 9):

> Хочу чтобы человек четко объяснил, зачем нужны три вида пикселей, когда какой вид пикселей используется и как переводить один вид пикселя в другой вид.

На самом деле, речь идет о двух видах пикселей: обычные и `DIP`. Введение `DIP` было необходимо для обеспечения соблюдения сохранности геометрических размеров на разных устройствах отображения информации.

**Простой пример**

Мы нарисовали на экране с `DPI=96` квадрат 24x24 пикселя. На этом экране он виден более-менее отчетливо. Но если это воспроизвести на экране с `DPI=144` и не применять масштабирование, то рисунок "физически" останется тот же, но его видимые геометрические размеры будут значительно меньше. Выход - масштабировать.

Для этих целей ввели понятие `DIP`-пикселя, который равен 1/96 "логического" пикселя. Что позволить производить более точное масштабирование. Ибо использование разных `DPI` разных устройств при масштабировании может давать дробные числа.

Вот неплохой пример от Майкрософт:

> For example, if the user's DPI setting is 144 DPI, and you ask Direct2D to draw a 200 × 100 rectangle, the rectangle will be 300 × 150 physical pixels. In addition, DirectWrite measures font sizes in DIPs, rather than points. To create a 12-point font, specify 16 DIPs (12 points = 1/6 logical inch = 96/6 DIPs). When the text is drawn on the screen, Direct2D converts the DIPs to physical pixels. The benefit of this system is that the units of measurement are consistent for both text and drawing, regardless of the current DPI setting.

И табличка соответствия:

```
   ===============+=================
    DPI-настройка | DIP-размер
   ===============+=================
        96        |  1 пиксель
       120        |  1.25 пикселя
       144        |  1.5 пиксель
   ===============+=================
```

**Формула масштабирования "физического" пикселя в DIP**

`DIPs = Физические_пиксели / (DPI/96.0)`

**Таким образом**

Применяя DIP, на разных устройствах с разным DPI - можно обеспечить приемлемую константность физических размеров отображаемого.

[image]

**CSS-Pixel / Device Pixel**

Пример1:

[image]

Пример2:

[image]

**Определение DIPs**

> The number of dips is equal to the number of `CSS` pixels that is optimal for viewing a website on the device at **100% zoom**

Comment: как это "На самом деле, речь идет о двух видах пикселей: обычные и DIP". когда я пишу, например, width:100px - задаю именно css-пиксели (масштабируемые пиксели). в этом видео, которое по ссылке (и в многих других статьях), сказано, что есть именно ТРИ вида пикселей, а не два. идею, как связаны hardware pixels и dip-pixels я понимаю

Comment: css-пиксель, которрый обозначается `px`, определяют как точку (скорее область) размером 1/96 дюйма. Это фиксированный **физический** размер. Если присмотреться формуле расчета, до ее можно записать как `DIPs = Hardware_Pixel / (DPI*CSS_Pixel)`. Добавлю в ответ рисунок про `css px`.

Comment: как это "css-пиксель - фиксированный физический размер"? например, я задаю диву width:100px, потом делаю зум ин (приближаю), при этом, див становится шире и выше - он УВЕЛИЧИЛСЯ в размерах, а остается по ширине те же 100 пикселей. это 100 визуальных масштабируемых пикселей CSS, насколько правильно я понимаю. это можно в девелопер тулс посмотреть

Comment: На сколько я понял, при зуме, отличном от 100% - не "визуальный размер пикселя" увеличивается, а увеличивается "визуальная ширина", которая вычисляется по формуле `визуальная ширина = размер пикселя * количество пикселей * зумфактор`. Таким образом, если мы скажем "у нас увеличился визуальный размер пикселя", это автоматом означает отсутствие зум-фактора. А это не так. Имхо. Тема на самом деле туманная - читал черновик (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/), не нашел там однозначного определения `css pixel size`, не говоря уж о формуле.