# Лучшее решение для растягивания растрового UI?

Tags: разработка-игр, gui, ui

Привет.

Давно интересуюсь темой "растягивающегося" UI.
Мне необходимо сделать "растягивающийся" UI.
Особых проблем в реализации нет, но есть одна:

1. Рендерер движка не поддерживает векторную графику
2. Реализовать рендеринг контролов без внешней графики не предоставляется возможным ввиду отсутствия нужных мне эффектов(а шейдеры для кнопок я писать не хочу)

т.е единственный выход - растровые спрайты.
Вопрос: Как сделать растягивающийся растровый UI но при этом, что бы это не выглядело как Minecraft?

Движок поддерживает только самую простую интерполяцию, как в пейнте(через d3dx), и есть ограничение на кол-во DrawCall

В том движке, где я работаю есть только скриптовый язык, поэтому модификация ренедера невозможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из решений, которое навеяно разборками в [`смежной теме`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604518/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-dip-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-css-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-device-pixels) - попробовать принципы адаптивного дизайна. Иными словами, для определенных областей, имеющих диапазоны `min` и `max` для ширин и высот - создать соответствующие наборы контролов.

Да, при растягивании работать будет "скачкообразно". Сперва "тянуться" промежутки между контролами. Как только область перескакивает в иной `mix-max` - прорисовываются контролы уже из другого, соответствующего, набора.

Если движок векторную графику не поддерживает, надеюсь, носитель информации вашего устройства - осилит с пару десятков (миллионов, шутка) наборов? :)

Comment: спасибо, но я же не могу рисовать на каждую пару width\height по контролу ;)


Это библиотека, и если с текстовым полем можно обойтись еще, то чекбокс или кнопку красивым без фотошопа уже не нарисуешь ;)

За исключением CSS и QSS

Comment: В разрезе набирающего популярность "адаптивного дизайна" - используют наборы разрешений типовых моделей смартфонов/планшетов. Там их не много, пару десятков. Умножьте ваш набор контролов на 50. Ну плюс еше 10 наборов на разрешения десктопов. Но я не настаиваю - решение за вами, моя только идея))

Comment: так дело то как раз в том что контролы будут рисоватся юзерами библиотеками(а точнее их дизайнерами если таковые у них будут), т.к решение предназначено для разработчиков игр на одном очень известном конструкторе, я думаю все уже догадались каком ;)

Comment: Про " очень известный конструктор" - прошу раскрыть военную тайну) А вот по "рисованию юзерами" ... могу привести грубую, но всеж, аналогию - редактор иконок. Формат ICO - по сути библиотека. Хочешь нарисовать иконки под все версии Default OS - предусмотри все поддерживаемые размеры для каждой версии. Буквально на прошлой неделе этим занимался. Работает просто изумительно. Ну а юзеры - ну пусть понимают, что целевой девайс не поддерживает векторную графику, и рисовать надо. Иначе удачи не видать.

Comment: Game Maker Studio

Comment: Оффтоп: бегло прочел, кроме Delphi, и декларируемого отсутствия наличия программинг-скилов, путного ниче не увидел. Для юзкейса 2D-гам я бы рекомендовал обратить внимание на фреймворки Haxe (http://haxe.org/use-cases/games/).

Comment: та я ради интереса пишу ну и попробую продавать т.к с GUI в GMS все мягко говоря сложно, у меня скиллы довольно нормальные ;)

Comment: Ясн. Ну ... э ... чего мог присоветовать - присоветовал) Удачи))

Comment: @Majestion, спасибо, поставил флаг лучшего ответа ;)